# Serial Port strange data display and crash

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I am trying to create vb.net program to get data from scales using serial port.

I don't know scales model, just Display model: IND231.

Problem is i get stupid data:

[image: PICTURE 1 with my program]

but if turn on Putty i get this:

[image: PICTURE 2 Putty Window]

As you see in putty there is only one line which refresh every sec, true weight is first two 00 (in middle), in my situation this line is not refreshing, but make a huge line and after 5-10 s, my program just crash.

My program code is:

```
Imports AxSerial

Public Class Form1
    Dim Q As Queue(Of String) = New Queue(Of String)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object,
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each s In System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
            lstPorts.Items.Add(s)
        Next s
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        Try
            If lstPorts.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
                MsgBox("Please select a port")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
                SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
                SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                SerialPort1.StopBits = 1
                SerialPort1.RtsEnable = False
                SerialPort1.PortName = lstPorts.SelectedItem.ToString
                SerialPort1.Open()
                Timer1.Start()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object,
        ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) _
        Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Q.Enqueue(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object,
           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        SyncLock Q
            While Q.Count > 0
                txtReceived.Text &= Q.Dequeue
            End While
        End SyncLock
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is IND321 Serial Port Parameters

```
SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
            SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
            SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            SerialPort1.StopBits = 1
            SerialPort1.RtsEnable = False
```

Im not sure with RtsEnable, i think this is FlowControl.

What i need to correct to get data like putty?

Comment: It looks to me like you are getting the same data... your Putty says ")0 00 00" and your textbox also says ")0 00 00" but is followed by a return. Try clearing the textbox every time your timer fires, before its updated with a new value

Comment: Smart. But now it's blinking and one time i get 00   00, next time )0, and next time just blank textbox.

Comment: Try using `ReadLine()`. You may need to set `.Newline` to `vbCr`.

Comment: Agree with @JimHewitt For our scale program we use ReadLine() and parse the weight and other items out of the response. Your program may be crashing because you never truncate the textbox.

Comment: Ok, i think i just fixed. What I did.
I used ReadTo(")"), and changed to `RichTextBox1.Text = Q.Dequeue().Replace(Chr(2), "")`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your scale/serial port is returning data in another format.
Check your scale specs.  It might be e72 or some other even/odd/bits/parity combination.

Comment: I checked at manual, everything is ok with parameters. Thank you.